# What's the p3 plug (audio) of smartphone safe volt/amper limits (to use as a communication way with microcontroller)?

Tags: arduino, microphone, smartphones

And with has some problem in use it without do "waves", I want to serialize data from microcontroler to smartphone like (-1 as inferior limit of tension, +1 as superior limit):

+1 (digital 1) -1 (digital 1) +0.5 (digital 0) -0.5 (digital 0), swaping +/- between bits ("frequency independent way")

**Obs:**(common TRRS/P3/3.5mm)

Comment: I know some smartphones support UART communication over the 3.5mm audio jack. Adapter: [TTL-232R-5V-AJ/TTL-232R-3V3-AJ](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/163/DS_TTL-232R_CABLES-217672.pdf). I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking though.

Comment: thanks @Seir, but what i want is not a protocol/software, i want know the limit of volts between the ground and microphone input to do the "hardware"/volt divisors to send from a gpio/digital pin signal to it in a safe way, without worry about my phone...

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic of what you have or how you are proposing to make your circuit. Are you asking about what peak voltage a consumer audio interface will output?

Comment: thansk, @winny "inverse" is the peak voltage that i can send from a system to a smartphone 3.5mm microfone input, (common ground)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official Android documentation says maximum output voltage drive for mic input is 150mV.

You can simply make the output adjustable with a potentiometer and start adjusting the voltage from zero upwards until it is high enough.